# Confusion about assumptions in proofs related to function restrictions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $f, b$ be functions where $\operatorname{dom}(f) = A, \operatorname{dom}(g) = B$ and $C = A \cap B.$ Show $f \cap g$ is a function and $\operatorname{dom}(f \cap g) = C \iff f \upharpoonright C = g \upharpoonright C$.

My proof:

Suppose $(x, y) \in f \cap g.$ Then $x \in C$. Also, $(x, y) \in f$ and $(x, y) \in g$ and so $f(x) = y$ and $g(x) = y$ which means $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in C$. Thus $f \upharpoonright C = g  \upharpoonright C.$

Suppose $f\upharpoonright C = g \upharpoonright C$ and $(x, y), (x, z) \in f \cap g.$ Then $(x, y), (x, z) \in f $ and $(x, y), (x, z) \in g $. Since both $f, g$ are functions, $y = z.$ Thus $f \cap g$ is a function $\square$

I ended up not using the given assumptions in either direction. Obviously, something must've gone wrong. What is wrong with the proof above? Thanks.

edit:

@ Rob Arthan

$(1)$ Suppose $(x, y), (x, z) \in f \cap g.$ Then $(x, y), (x, z) \in f $ and $(x, y), (x, z) \in g $. Since both $f, g$ are functions, $y = z.$ Thus $f \cap g$ is a function.

$(2)$. Suppose $x \in C$. Also suppose $(x, y) \in f$ and $(x, y) \in g$. Then $f(x) = y$ and $g(x) = y$ which means $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in C$. Thus $f \upharpoonright C = g  \upharpoonright C.$ In the other direction, suppose $x \in C.$ Since $f \upharpoonright C = g  \upharpoonright C$, then $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f \upharpoonright C) \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $x \in \operatorname{dom}(g \upharpoonright C) \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(g)$. Thus $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f \cap g).$ Now assuming $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f \cap g)$, if $f \upharpoonright C = g \upharpoonright C$ with $(x, y) \in f \upharpoonright C$, then $x \in C.$

Does it make sense?

Comment: The problem is a bit misleadingly stated: what it means is: given $f$ and $g$ are functions and $A$, $B$ and $C$ are as defined, then (1) show $f \cap g$ is a function and (2)  show $\mathrm{dom} (f \cap g) = C \iff f \upharpoonright C = g \upharpoonright C$. Does it make sense now?

Comment: You're tacitly using the assumption that $C=A\cap B$ in the first case when you go from $(x,y)\in f\cap g$ to $x\in C$, so it isn't true that you're not using the assumptions. You've just not used them very explicitly.

Comment: @RobArthan, I edited my post. Please, see if that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Your proof of part (2) isn't right. It should have two parts one for $\Rightarrow$ and one for $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: @RobArthan, I tried fixing $(2).$ Please, see if it works now.

Comment: I have written a corrected proof of (2) as an answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of (1) is fine. For (2):

$\Rightarrow$: assume $\mathrm{dom}(f \cap g) = C$. Then for any $x \in C$, $f(x) = g(x)$ (i.e., there is a $y$ such that $(x, y) \in f$ and $(x, y) \in g)$, so the restriction $f \upharpoonright C = \{(x, y) \in f \mid x \in C\}$ of $f$ to $C$ is equal to the restriction $g \upharpoonright C = \{(x, y) \in g \mid x \in C\}$ of $g$ to $C$.

$\Leftarrow$: assume $f \upharpoonright C = g \upharpoonright C$.  We have to prove that $\mathrm{dom}(f \cap g) = C$, i.e., that (i), $\mathrm{dom}(f \cap g) \subseteq C$ and (ii), $C \subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f \cap g)$.   (i) is easy to prove (see proof of (1)). For (ii), if $x \in C$, then by our assumption, $f(x) = (f \upharpoonright C)(x) = (g \upharpoonright C)(x) = g(x)$. so $(x, f(x)) = (x, g(x)) \in f \cap g$, giving us that $x \in \mathrm{dom}(f \cap g)$. Hence $C \subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f \cap g)$ and we are done.